# Autofac Register closed types and retrieve them at run time

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, autofac-configuration

I have an Interface that will take in a generic type `T`

```
 internal interface IQuestion<T> where T : IWithOptionsId
 {
     Task<T> Provide(Guid id);
 }
```

Following by that I will implement this interface in multiple classes. For example

```
public class SomeProvider : IQuestion<OptionsClass>
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public SomeProvider(IRepository repository)
    {

        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<OptionsClass> Provide(Guid id)

    ...
}
```

To register this with outofac I used this

```
Autofac.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQuestion<>));
```

My question is this. I have multiple instances for this interface. How do I access different instance once at the run time? If my `IQuestion<T>` will take in `Options` class and also it will take in `Answer` class how can I get an instance of those classes during run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just inject the instance itself. Not great practice, but it should work:

```
public SomeClass(SomeProvider<OptionsClass> provider)
```

You could also try creating a named instance when you register it, and inject that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710779/autofac-resolve-a-specific-dependency-to-a-named-instance) and [this](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for the named registrations. Wasn't familiar with proper terminology. Thank you.